# package does not exist in compile

Tags: java

My project was working fine. ut suddenly i started to get errors. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVF00.png)

Meanwhile i can see the package.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCUcP.png)

I think it may to do with "gradle". I started to use it recently and don't understand this technology well. My build.gradle

```
    group 'www.www'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile 'com.github.badoualy:kotlogram:1.0.0-RC3'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.5'
}
```

thanks a lot

Comment: well, that is what happens when you use packages which are not part of the api. What do you think `com.sun.istack.internal` stands for?

Comment: "*I think it may to do with "gradle".*" - I don't think so. Especially because there is nothing within your `build.gradle` indicating a dependency to `com.sun.istack.internal`.

Comment: In case it isn't clear yet from the others' comments: You should not use classes from the package `com.sun.istack.internal`. Remove any `import` statements from your code that import from that package, and fix your code so that it does not use classes from that package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed import and now all fine.

```
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable;
```